# Android: К проекту не подключается проект библиотеки android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, java, библиотеки

Все выполнено по этой инструкции: [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/189678/)

В style.xml прописываю это:

```
    <resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Ошибка:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Захожу по такому пути: 
Properties -> Android -> Library >> видно что проект библиотеки не подключен. Добавляю заново, сохраняю, собираю проект >> результат тот же.

В чем может быть еще причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было что-то подобное. Решил по-моему или обновлением ADT через SDK Manager или банальным перезапуском Eclipse. Еще важный момент: при подключении либы к проекту НЕ НУЖНО ставить галочку "Copy project to workspace". Попробуйте. Кроме того, опишите как подключаете более подробно.

Comment: Мне не помогло ни обновление, ни перезапуском.
Подключаю так: Мой проект, правая кнопка мыши > Properties > Android > libraries > add > android-support-v7-appcompat > ok 
сохраняю, запускаю заново это же и вижу это: http://joxi.ru/sFSXUtg5CbCGW47TSHU

Comment: Решение нашлось?

Answer (score 2):

Добавь `values-v21` папку в `RES` и в нее `styles.xml` c кодом

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light" >
```

А в остальных `values`-ах все по стандарту как и было (ну типа Holo т.п)